# regarding efficiently modifying entry values in an numpy array without writing iteration explicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have a NumPy array A, of shape `(1000,)`. For any component of `A`, if it has a negative value, I need to assign it 0. How to efficiently perform this without explicitly using iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
A[A<0]=0
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the existing array in-place you could do:

```
A[A < 0] = 0
```

Or to create a new array with the desired value, you could do:

```
B = np.maximum(A, 0)
```